# How to append a Gradle Task without using `dependsOn`?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, java-native-interface

I am using Gradle to build a Java project involving native libraries. I have a task `jniHeaders` defined:

```
jniHeaders.dependsOn classes
```

so when I type `gradle jniHeaders`, it will compile the Java classes and generate JNI headers. So far so good.

But I feel that typing `gradle jniHeaders` is not very natural. And 99% of the time, if you compile Java classes successfully, you'd want to generate JNI headers as well. It would be nice if I could `gradle classes` to compile Java classes and generate JNI headers in one step.

In other words, **I want to add the task `jniHeaders` to the end of the task `classes`, but only if `classes` is completed sucessfully and actually did some work.**

`classes.doLast` comes to mind, but I am unable to tell it to execute another task. `classes.finalizedBy jniHeaders` works to an extent, but generates JNI headers regardless of the outcome of `classes`. I suppose I could add some Groovy logic to get the exact behavior I want, but I also suspect there must be an easier way.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Is it just the notion of invoking a seemingly arbitrary task that's bugging you?  I might be tempted to define another task `allTheThings` (or whatever!) that simply depends on both `classes` and `jniHeaders`.  That seems a lot simpler than having to add boutique build logic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of modelling a build as a graph of tasks is that there's a simple and robust execution model. I suggest you create a function `compileJNIHeaders()` and put it somewhere Gradle can access it (the `build.gradle` itself as well as `buildSrc/src/main/groovy`), so you can easily develop and test it.

This function can be executed in the most appropriate step:

- `classes.doFirst` (if the headers are for your own code)
- `classes.doLast` (if the headers are for dependent projects)
- put in a task `compileJNIHeaders` that is a dependency of the task that you use to package your project in its deployment format

Comment: thank you. I got too caught up with trying to manipulate the dependency graph, and forgot about the easiest way to modularize.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question:

1. Add the task `jniHeaders` to execute after successfully compiling java classes.
2. Only perform `jniHeaders` task if any work was done.

Since `classes` task is an assembly of `processResources` and `compileJava` (see [java plugin doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)), I think it's better to hook into the `compileJava` task. As you've found yourself, this can be done with `finalizedBy`. In addition, you need to skip the task if no work was done, e.g. by adding an `onlyIf` statement to your `jniHeaders` task.

Example:

```
task jniHeaders {
    onlyIf { !sourceSets.main.allJava.empty }
    doLast {
        println "GENERATE JNI HEADERS for $project.name"
    }
}
compileJava.finalizedBy jniHeaders
```

Comment: Thank you. But I try your code and it does not really work as desired. Even if `compileJava` fails, `jniHeader` still gets executed because presumably `allJava` is not empty! (I did not start with a clean build directory) Anyway, I have adopted @Raffaele's solution. Thank you for the suggestion.